# android Facebook SDK 4.18.0 for eclipse

Tags: android, facebook

I am using eclipse. I need facebook sdk integration in my app. Current android sdk version is 20. Please give me any suggestions.

Comment: Any reasons for still using eclipse?

Comment: refer [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads) and [download](https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=facebook-android-sdk-4.18.0.zip)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should go with Android Studio but if you want to integrate FB from eclipse then go with Click [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/)!